# Problem with output csv while comparing csv files and extracting columns

Tags: csv, awk

I am trying to compare two csv files based on their first and output first two columns of file 1 and second and third columns of file 2 to a new csv file

Example:

file1.csv

```
asdf123,1  
adfg234,2  
asdf567,3
```

file2.csv

```
asdf123,q,w  
asdf567,r,t
```

desired output

```
asdf123,1,q,w  
adfg234,2,NA  
asdf567,3,r,t
```

I used the following code

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next};{if (i in a) {print a[$1] "," $2} else {print a[$1] "," "NA"}}' file1.csv file2.csv > output.csv
```

However, the command after else doesn't seem to work and has empty rows in the place and in addition, the out put is printed as follows (with new lines in between):

```
asdf123,1  
*blank space* q,w  

asdf567,3  
*blank space* r,t
```

I am new to scripting. Can someone please guide me to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With bash, sort and GNU join:

```
join -t ',' -a 1 -e 'NA' <(sort file1.csv) <(sort file2.csv) -o 1.1,1.2,2.2,2.3
```

Output:

```
adfg234,2,NA,NA
asdf123,1,q,w
asdf567,3,r,t
```

---

See: `man join`

Comment: Thank you. My output csv file has the two columns from the second csv file in a new line throughout. Can you please advise me on this.

Comment: In that case, I suggest: `join -t ',' -a 1 -e 'NA' <(dos2unix < file1.csv | sort) <(dos2unix < file2.csv | sort) -o 1.1,1.2,2.2,2.3`

Answer (score 1):

There were a couple of bugs in your script:

```
$ awk -F, '
FNR==NR {
    a[$1]=$0
    next
}
{
    if($1 in a)              # no i anywhere, use $1
        print a[$1] "," $2 
    else 
        print $0 "," "NA"    # cant use a[$1] in this else 
}' file2 file1               # file order
```

Output now:

```
asdf123,q,w,1
adfg234,2,NA
asdf567,r,t,3
```

And it won't match your output, since the file order changed, without some more effort:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","
}
FNR==NR {
    key=$1                  # $0="1,2,3" key=1
    $1=""                   # $0=",2,3"
    a[key]=$0               # a[1]=",2,3"
    next
}
{
    if ($1 in a) 
        print $1,$2 a[$1]
    else 
        print $0,"NA"
}' file2 file1
```

Output this time:

```
asdf123,1,q,w
adfg234,2,NA
asdf567,3,r,t
```